# Getting the difference between 2 matrices or data frames that are not numerical in R

Tags: r, matrix, difference

Here is my conundrum. I'm trying to track patient statuses in my study from day to day. I currently have built a code that does this and the output looks like this:

```
        P1    Waitlisted    
        P80   Lab Appointment
        P19   Lab Appointment
        P26   Waitlisted
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can get the difference between a report I run today versus one the one I ran yesterday to basically quickly track for any new patients that have shown up in my list or any patients that have been removed. So if the next day, my data frame is

```
        P20     Waitlisted
        P1      Waitlisted    
        P80     Lab Appointment
        P19     Lab Appointment
        P5      Lab Appointment
        P26     Waitlisted
```

I would get the output of:

```
        P20     Waitlisted
        P5      Lab Appointment
```

As the difference between the two or if the next day if the results are

```
        P1    Waitlisted    
        P80   Lab Appointment
        P80   Waitlisted
        P19   Lab Appointment
        P26   Waitlisted
```

The output would generate:

```
        P80   Waitlisted
```

I would also want to converse if a patient has been removed from my list the day before so if I get an output like

```
        P1    Waitlisted    
        P80   Lab Appointment
        P26   Waitlisted
```

There would be a way to know that P19 Lab Appointment is no longer in my list today.

I've tried the following codes, but I only get logical factors with no way of knowing what is true and false.

```
    >apply(apply(df1,2,`==`,df2),1,any)
    [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA    NA    NA  TRUE  TRUE FALSE 
    FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE    NA  TRUE FALSE FALSE
    [20] FALSE    NA    NA FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA  TRUE 
    FALSE FALSE  TRUE    NA    NA  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
    [39]  TRUE  TRUE    NA    NA    NA  TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use anti-joins to get the differences between days. Specifically in `data.table` you might do:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1); setDT(df2)
removed_patient_status <- df1[!df2, on = c("status", "patient")]
new_patient_status <- df2[!df1, on = c("status", "patient")]

removed_patient_status
#Empty data.table (0 rows) of 2 cols: patient,status

new_patient_status
#   patient          status
#1:     P20      Waitlisted
#2:      P5 Lab Appointment
```

Or in `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
removed_patient_status <- anti_join(df1, df2, by = c("status", "patient"))
new_patient_status <- anti_join(df2, df1, by = c("status", "patient"))
```

---

**Data:**

```
df1 <- data.frame(patient = c("P1", "P80", "P19", "P26"), status = c("Waitlisted", "Lab Appointment", "Lab Appointment", "Waitlisted"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(patient = c("P20", "P1", "P80", "P19", "P5","P26"), status = c("Waitlisted", "Waitlisted", "Lab Appointment", "Lab Appointment", "Lab Appointment","Waitlisted"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first question:

```
df1 <- data.frame(P = c("P1","P80","P19","P26"), Status=c("Waitlisted","Lab Appointment", "Lab Appointment", "Waitlisted"))      

df2 <- data.frame(P = c("P20","P1","P80","P19","P5","P26"), Status=c("Waitlisted","Waitlisted","Lab Appointment","Lab Appointment","Lab Appointment", "Waitlisted"))                 

df2[!(paste(df2$P, df2$Status) %in% paste(df1$P, df1$Status)),] #removed patients
```